# Using a string to access something in a module programatically

Tags: rust

I am making a program that accepts strings that correlate to keys on a keyboard using [Enigo](https://docs.rs/enigo/0.1.2/enigo/index.html). Currently, I'm using a match statement to access the modules, I'd ultimately like to use some way of accessing them using the strings themselves.

```
match action.as_str() {
    "Meta" => Key::Meta,
    "Control" => Key::Control,
    "Alt" => Key::Alt,
    "Tab" => Key::Tab,
    "Shift" => Key::Shift,
    "Space" => Key::Space,
    "Esc" => Key::Escape,
    &_ => Key::Layout(action.chars().next().unwrap()),
}
```

Is there a way do this using something like a `module.get(&str)` or something?

Comment: Is `Key` an enum?

Comment: You'll need to `match` the output of this and perform the appropriate action.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes it's an enum